# How to introduce a variable in a Markup function in Flask

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a python flask function that uses a flash() to give a user an opportunity to undo an action. I am trying to present a variable "task_id" within a Markup(). This variable is defined earlier in the function before the flash is called. I am trying to assign a data-* attribute the value of this variable, but it is not working.

```
flash(task_name + " was marked complete " + Markup('<a href="#" class="toggle_task" data-task_id=task_id>UNDO</a>'))
```

I also tried using jinja syntax, like {{task_id}} but this does not work either. How can I pass a variable into the Markup()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
flash(task_name + " was marked complete " + Markup('<a href="#" class="toggle_task" data-task_id={}>UNDO</a>'.format(task_id)))
```